# How to convert a str to a single element list in python

Tags: python

I have a `str` variable: `var_1 = "hello"` , and I want to convert it to a single element `list`, I try this:

```
>>> list(var_1)
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

which is not the `['hello']` that I want.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Just put square brackets

```
>>> var_1 = "hello"
>>> [var_1]
['hello']
```

Comment: why do `list(var_1)` and `[var_1]` have different behavior? How do they differ?

Answer (score 7):

Just do the following:

```
var_1 = ['hello']
```

Answer (score 6):

It can be useful to add a check before doing so, as such:

```
if not isinstance(var_1, list): var_1 = [var_1]
```

A use case for this code is in functions that can take either a string or a list of strings and want the functions to handle that silently. E.g.:

```
def dataframe_key_columns(dataframe, keys):
    if not isinstance(keys, list): keys = [keys]
    return [dataframe[key] for key in keys]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24694265)

Comment: Is this better?

Answer (score 5):

Does `var1 = [var1]` accomplish what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Let me provide you a much easier and authentic way to do it.

`s='hello'
 L=[]
 L.append(s)`

You will get a list with 'hello' as its element.
And you can use the list L anyway you like.